# Emotion package issue-React

Tags: emotion

Error: The `emotion` package has been renamed to `@emotion/css`. Please import it like this `import { css } from '@emotion/css'`.

i already imported in my App.js

Comment: Hey Ansh, can you provide more info about your code, so the community can reproduce or at least have a better understanding of your issue. You can check how to write question in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - 
Also can you provide the full error stack trace, maybe the error come from another `js` file where you also use `emotion`

Comment: I am uisng below code, then getting this error

const App = props => {
  const shareButtonProps = {
    url: "https://github.com/greglobinski/react-custom-share",
    network: "Facebook",
    text: "Give it a try - react-custom-share component",
    longtext:
      "Social sharing buttons for React. Use one of the build-in themes or create a custom one from the scratch."
  };

  return <ShareButton {...shareButtonProps}>
    <FaFacebook />
  </ShareButton>;
};